# Why my response from flask api is multipled?

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

I am learning to build an API with Python and Flask. I don't know why, but sometimes and I get response which is multipled. Now I have 67 records in my database, but the response from API has much more items.
Here's the api code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)    
#Create an instance of MySQL
mysql = MySQL()    
#Create an instance of Flask RESTful API
api = Api(app)

#Set database credentials in config.
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'xxx'

#Initialize the MySQL extension
mysql.init_app(app)
keys_dict = ["id", "link", "title", "date", "image", "description", "tag"]
final_dict = []
class PostList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * from table ORDER BY date """)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
       
        for m in rows:
            final_dict.append(dict(zip(keys_dict, m)))
        return jsonify(final_dict)
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

api.add_resource(PostList, '/', endpoint='')

if __name__  == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The response sometimes looks normal, but usually is much bigger than it should be:
[image]
I'd prefer not to post an endpoint here for obvious reasons, but I think the problem is in the above code.
I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: API is hosted on pythonanywhere. When I reload it - it gives valid number of items. But after this, every next request gives multipled response.

Comment: can you expand, see & share what the output looks like for the JSON items. that will help with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following portion of code as below:

```
#Initialize the MySQL extension
mysql.init_app(app)
keys_dict = ["id", "link", "title", "date", "image", "description", "tag"]

class PostList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        final_dict = []
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * from table ORDER BY date """)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
       
        for m in rows:
            final_dict.append(dict(zip(keys_dict, m)))
        return jsonify(final_dict)
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

**change**: *define `final_dict` assignment in the `get` function of the class* `PostList`